# Event listener is not removed in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, addeventlistener, use-effect, removeeventlistener

I have registered an event for handling the hardware back button press in the **Home Screen**. Whenever I **click** the **back** button when I am in the **home screen**, it will ask me for the exit confirmation alert box. I want this behaviour to happen only in the **Home screen**, not in any other screen. When I am in some other screen, let's say **Setting Screen** and I click the back button, it still shows me the exit confirmation alert box. It seems like the event I registered on the **Home Screen** has not been removed.

```
const backAction = () => {
    Alert.alert('Close the KhataBook app?', 'Are you sure you want to exit?', [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => null,
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      {text: 'YES', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()},
    ]);
    return true;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      backAction,
    );
    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Solved using useFocusEffect from @react-navigation/native instead of useEffect for wrapping the event listener adding and removing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove listener like in docs , with removeEventListener method

```
  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);

    return () =>
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react navigation you can achieve that by doing the following:

```
  useFocusEffect(() => {
        const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
            'hardwareBackPress', ()=>{ navigation.goBack(); return true; });
        return () => {
            backHandler.remove();
        };
    });
```